# detect if all text fits into block

Tags: jquery, text, scroll, block

I have a lot of text inside of a fixed-size block. I need to determine if the text fits in the block. How can I do that? Preferably with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)